# Firebase mapping with logged in user - PERMISSION DENIED Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Am new to this Firebase and finding it hard to understand the technology. So I am using this `Firebase` to store my Android application Data. The application, as of now, contains an option for user to login and create a Customer. The idea is to add, edit and list out customer details based on the user logged in. Below is the Rule, that I've added of my own, which am still confused of as in the way am doing it is right or not.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$UID": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $UID",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $UID"
      }
    },
    "customers":{
      "$UID":{
        ".read": "auth.uid == $UID", //to make sure that only proper customer gets displayed and updated/added
        ".write": "auth.uid == $UID",

      "$CID":{

        "UserId":{
          ".validate": "(data.exists() && data.val() == newData.val()) || newData.val() == auth.uid"
        },
        "CustomerName":{
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        },
        "CustomerCode":{
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length<4"
        },
        "CustomerLimit":{}
      }
      }
    }
  }
}​
```

and here is the login part in application.

```
​auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
.addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        ViewDialog.hideLoading();
        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Authentication failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Authentication success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
});
```

That logs in successfully and here is how I try to add Customer.

```
​public class AddCustomer extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialEditText editTextCustName,editTextCustCode,editTextCustLimit;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    private String customerId;
    FloatingActionButton fabSaveUpdate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_customer);
        editTextCustName=(MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustName);
        editTextCustCode=(MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustCode);
        editTextCustLimit=(MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustLimit);
        fabSaveUpdate=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateUpdateCustomer);
        fabSaveUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String customerName=editTextCustName.getText().toString().trim();
                String customerCode=editTextCustCode.getText().toString().trim();
                Double customerLimit=TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextCustLimit.getText().toString())?0d:Double.parseDouble(editTextCustLimit.getText().toString().trim());
                mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                mFirebaseInstance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
                // get reference to 'customers' node
                mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("customers");
                Customer customer=new Customer(customerName,customerCode,customerLimit,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                createUser(customer);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creating new user node under 'users'
     */
    private void createUser(final Customer customer) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(customerId)) {
            customerId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
        }
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(customerId).setValue(customer);
        //addUserChangeListener();
    }

    /**
     * User data change listener
     */
    private void addUserChangeListener() {
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(customerId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Customer customer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);

                Log.e(TAG, "Customer data is changed!" + customer.getCustomerName() + ", " + customer.getCustomerCode());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read user", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer
{

    private String CustomerName;
    private String CustomerCode;
    private Double CustomerLimit;
    private String UserId; //to store reference to current logged in user
    public Customer(String custName,String custCode, Double custLimit, String userId){
       this.CustomerName=custName;
       this.CustomerCode=custCode;
       this.CustomerLimit=custLimit;
       this.UserId=userId;
    }
    //getter and setters ommitted.
}
```

But I always keep getting `PERMISSION DENIED` whenever I try to add new Customer after login. I know it is because of `read` and `write` options set in the `Rule` but am I missing something here. Is there any Authorization part I need to do here before adding? My assumption was logging in was enough to authorize the further operations. Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem description and code refer to "users" and "customers", but it is not clear if they are different.  The code adds a `Customer` under /customers in the database, but the method is named `createUser()` and the comment says: *Creating new user node under 'users'*.  You have security rules for both /users and /customers. It's not clear is the /user rules are needed or used.

If a customer is really just a user, then as Rohit suggests in his answer, you want to store customers using the UID  as the key rather than generating the key using `push()`.

The reason the posted code is failing is because there are no rules for path /customer.  For a quick fix that will limit access to signed-in users, update the rules as shown below.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$UID": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $UID",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $UID"
      }
    },
    "customers":{
        ".read": "auth != null",  //ADD THIS
        ".write": "auth != null", //ADD THIS
      "$UID":{  // I don't understand what this is for.  Needed?
        ".read": "auth.uid == $UID", //to make sure that only proper customer gets displayed and updated/added
        ".write": "auth.uid == $UID",

      "$CID":{
        "UserId":{
          ".validate": "(data.exists() && data.val() == newData.val()) || newData.val() == auth.uid"
        },
        "CustomerName":{
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        },
        "CustomerCode":{
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length<4"
        },
        "CustomerLimit":{}
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.. As of now, the user is registered by us directly into the db by keying in the values and there is no external option through application.. Once the user is created, he will be able to create customers and that customers should be mapped with the current logged in user.. That's the whole purpose.. As per your comment **// I don't understand what this is for.  Needed?** it might be wrong assumption as I did not completely understood the logic behind this.. I was thinking `read` and `write` on customers will be done only when logged in user is valid..

Comment: ..to do this operation.. Correct me if am wrong please.. Has there been any great awesome tutorial for these type of requirement or something similar, Could you please share the same? because the one I've seen till now only shows to do without authentication where read and write are `true`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: The most complete description  of security rules I have found are the various sections of this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).  One important concept is that permissions [cascade down the tree](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade).

Comment: Thanks buddy.. Your answer and 2nd link from your last comment helped pretty much.. Thank you so much once again for your time and effort.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The UID in `auth.uid` is a special ID given to a use by Firebase Auth. The key generated by `push().getKey()` is a timestamped unique key which is not the same as `auth.uid`.

I think you could use the UID generated by Firebase to store the customer data directly instead of your own ID. You can get the UID of the current user using

```
currentUserUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
```

EDIT: On second thought.. maybe you  just missed a `.child(currentUserUid)` when you go to the "customers" node